# Best way to convert an appended list to CSV file in python

Tags: python

i have featureStr as a list appended each column upto 34. Now i want to put it into a table using .csv excel sheet and also like to add header for each column. How can i do that?

```
featureStr.append( featMat[i][0])
#print (featureStr)
featureStr.append(featMat[i][1] )


featureStr.append( featMat[i][2] )
featureStr.append( featMat[i][3] )
featureStr.append( featMat[i][4] )
featureStr.append( featMat[i][5] )
featureStr.append( featMat[i][6] )
```

Comment: please be a little more specific. what do these columns look like? what is the header you want to add?

Comment: In Python, we name variables and functions with `lowercase_with_underscores` instead of `camelCase`. So `feature_str` instead of `featureStr`

Comment: Use a [`csv.writer`](https://docs.python.org/library/csv.html#csv.writer) and just pass your list to `csv.writer(your_file_object_here).writerows(your_list_here`